# Can we fuse Linear with BatchNorm parameters

Tags: pytorch

I would like to remove the BatchNorm from my model. So, I thought about fusing it with Linear. My model structure is like:

- `Linear -> ReLU -> BatchNorm -> Dropout -> Linear`

I tried fusing `BatchNorm -> Linear` and I couldn't fuse with my code available. Is there any way to fuse the BatchNorm with any of the above layers.

Comment: Do you want to replace batch norm layer with other layer? Share the code you have tried

Comment: Ya , I want to fuse(learnable parameters) of  Bnorm with near by available layer

Answer (score 0):

````
class DummyModule_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DummyModule_1, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        # print("Dummy, Dummy.")
        return x


def fuse_1(linear, bn):
    w = linear.weight
    print(w.size())
    mean = bn.running_mean
    var_sqrt = torch.sqrt(bn.running_var + bn.eps)

    beta = bn.weight
    gamma = bn.bias

    if linear.bias is not None:
        b = linear.bias
    else:
        b = mean.new_zeros(mean.shape)

    w = w.cuda()
    b = b.cuda()
    w = w * (beta / var_sqrt).reshape([4096, 1])
    b = (b - mean)/var_sqrt * beta + gamma
    fused_linear = nn.Linear(linear.in_features,
                         linear.out_features)
                                             
    fused_linear.weight = nn.Parameter(w)
    fused_linear.bias = nn.Parameter(b)
    return fused_linear


def fuse_module_1(m):
    children = list(m.named_children())
    c = None
    cn = None
    global c1
    global count
    global c18

    for name, child in children:
        print("name is",name,"child is",child)
       
         

        if name == 'linear':
          count = count+1 
          
          if count == 2:
            c18 = child
            print("c18 is",c18)

          else:
            fuse_module_1(child)

        if name =='2' and isinstance(child,nn.BatchNorm1d):
          print("child is",child)
          bc = fuse_1(c18,child)
          m.classifier[1].linear = bc
          m.classifier[2] = DummyModule_1(


        else:
            #fuse_module_1(child)
          fuse_module_1(child)```
````